# Form multiple records from a CSV in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

Need some light on the following:

I have the following CSV data:

```
0007,X1B2,"John,Jerome, Michelle", Kentucky,"Lawyer,Physician, Cardiologist",765468
```

The data consists of multiple values within "". I'm having challenges in reformatting the data into the following format:

```
0007,X1B2,John,Kentucky,Lawyer,765468,
0007,X1B2,Jerome,Kentucky, Physician,765468,
0007,X1B2,Michelle,Kentucky,Cardiologist,765468
```

I've read the data from a CSV file and stored it in a variable. Kindly enlighten. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have data in following format.

```
var row = [0007,"X1B2","John,Jerome, Michelle", "Kentucky","Lawyer,Physician, Cardiologist",765468]
```

Then your code will be.

```js
const row = [0007, "X1B2", "John,Jerome, Michelle", "Kentucky", "Lawyer,Physician,Cardiologist", 765468]

// Split string by comma.

const nameArr = row[2].split(',');
const professionArr = row[4].split(',');

let result = nameArr.map((name, index) => [row[0], name, row[1], row[3], professionArr[index], row[5]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have a multi-line csv and when I read the file into a variable with `str.split('\n')`, all the contents get read into a single array index.

Comment: @GPR try to split with \n\r

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get every row of csv in JS variable. You can refer following code snippet:

```
var row = [0007,"X1B2","John,Jerome, Michelle", "Kentucky","Lawyer,Physician, Cardiologist",765468]

var col3Values = [];
if(row[2] && row[2].trim().length > 0) {
    col3Values = row[2].split(",");
}

var col5Values = [];
if(row[4] && row[4].trim().length > 0) {
    col5Values = row[4].split(",");
}

var newRows = [];

for(var i=0;i<col3Values.length; i++) { 
    var newRow = [];
    newRow.push(row[0]);
    newRow.push(row[1]);
    newRow.push(col3Values[i]);
    newRow.push(row[3]);
    newRow.push(col5Values[i]);
    newRow.push(row[5]);
    newRows.push(newRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lines = [];
var text = '0007,X1B2,"John,Jerome, Michelle", Kentucky,"Lawyer,Physician, Cardiologist",765468';
var fields = text.split("\"");
var names = fields[1].split(",");
var profession = fields[3].split(",");
fields = text.split(",");
names.forEach(function(name, i){
 lines[i] = fields[0] + ',' + fields[1] + ',' + name + ',' + fields[5] + ',' + profession[i] + ',' + fields[9];
    console.log(lines[i]);
})
```